# How to excecute code after Flask `app.run()` statement (run a Flask app and a function in parallel, execute code while Flask server is running)

Tags: python, flask

Recently added Flask to a sample infinite-loop which randomly prints words. However, when adding `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` the code after that line won't execute after I stop Flask running.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

    while True:  # won't run until I press stop once (stop Flask) when running directly from IDE
        ...
```

What I want is to be able to run the `while` loop while the Flask app is running.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to execute some code immediately after the server starts?

Comment: @TrietDoan yes, the idea is to trigger calls to yet another API with requests randomly without needing calls to the service (the one I'm running with Flask). I would like to have Flask available only because of its healthcheck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can do what you want by using multithreading:**

```
from flask import Flask
import threading
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, World!"

def run_app():
    app.run(debug=False, threaded=True)

def while_function():
    i = 0
    while i < 20:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        i += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    first_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_app)
    second_thread = threading.Thread(target=while_function)
    first_thread.start()
    second_thread.start()
```

**Output:**

```
 * Serving Flask app "app"
 * Environment: production
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on [...] (Press CTRL+C to quit)
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
[...]
```

The idea is simple:

- create 2 functions, one to run the app and an other to execute the wile loop,
- and then execute each function in a seperate thread, making them run in parallel

**You can do this with multiprocessing instead of multithreading too:**

The (main) differences here is that the functions will run on different CPUs and in memory spaces.

```
from flask import Flask
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

# Helper function to easly  parallelize multiple functions
def parallelize_functions(*functions):
    processes = []
    for function in functions:
        p = Process(target=function)
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

# The function that will run in parallel with the Flask app
def while_function():
    i = 0
    while i < 20:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        i += 1

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, World!"

def run_app():
    app.run(debug=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parallelize_functions(while_function, run_app)
```

**If you want to use `before_first_request` proposed by @Triet Doan**: you will have to pass the while function as an argument of `before_first_request` like this:

```
from flask import Flask
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

def while_function(arg):
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        i += 1

@app.before_first_request(while_function)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    print("index is running!")
    return "Hello world"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

In this setup, the while function will be executed, and, when it will be finished, your app will run, but I don't think that was what you were asking for?

Comment: Exactly what you added first is what I was looking for, multithreading! I'm trying to avoid calls to the service at all costs to keep it simple.

Comment: However, something seems off. Still can't manage to run both. May be something in my local probably, since threaded behavior is totally expected and should run as you said.

Comment: What is "off" exactly?

Comment: Same behavior as before, I mean, needing to stop Flask first to the while loop starts executing.

Comment: Very strange... To be sure I tested these 3 samples on 4 different machines and they work as intended... Did you just copy paste the code and ran it or did you modified anything?

Comment: It was a copypaste directly yes, something strange going on for sure. Tried with multiprocessing and now it works flawlessly!

Answer (score 9):

### Update 2023

To run some code before starting a Flask server, it is now recommended to use the [Application Factory Pattern](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/appfactories/).

Basically, the idea is replacing `app = Flask(__name__)` with a proper function which returns the `app` object. For example, we can have something like this in our `__init__.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_redis import FlaskRedis


# Globally accessible libraries
db = SQLAlchemy()
r = FlaskRedis()


def init_app():
    """Initialize the core application."""
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object('config.Config')

    # Initialize Plugins
    db.init_app(app)
    r.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        # before_first_request equivalent here

        # Include our Routes
        from . import routes

        # Register Blueprints
        app.register_blueprint(auth.auth_bp)
        app.register_blueprint(admin.admin_bp)

        return app
```

So, for whatever was put under `before_first_request` before, just put them now under the `with app.app_context():`.

Then, in the application entrance (e.g. `main.py`), we simply use it:

```py
app = init_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

For more information, [this nice article](https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-application-factory/) is recommended.

---

### Deprecated since Flask 2.2

You can use [before_first_request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request) instead. Functions decorated with `@app.before_first_request` will run once before the first request to this instance of the application.

The code looks like this:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    print("index is running!")
    return "Hello world"

@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request_func():
    print("This function will run once")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

The code in `before_first_request_func` will be executed once before the first request to the server. Therefore, after starting the Flask instance, one can simulate the first request to the server using `curl` or so.

Comment: This does not work. Have you tested your code?

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"? Did you see the text printed out?

Comment: Not it does not print the text. From the doc (`https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/`) you have to pass the function as an argument to `before_first_request(func)`. I edited my answer because i can't post the correct code here in comment.

Comment: To get the text printed, one has to make a request to the server instance.

Comment: When used to connect to another service such as Cassandra it creates a "cold start" problem (timeout during re-connection on every request following inactivity period long enough to cause disconnections from the service).

Comment: Be cautious during tests, as it may mislead you in yet another way: functions decorated with `@app.before_first_request` can be called and entered into during than just the first request, until all `app` forks made by `gunicorn` are initialized by receiving at least one request.

Comment: Before_first_request is deprecated in Flask 2.2 so this won't work for many

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've updated my answer with the latest approach.